# Correct use of object-complement

Tags: grammar, pronouns, translation, structure, object-complements

1. **Books are great blessings.**
2. **Books are a great blessing.**

Which sentence is correct? If both are correct, then what's the difference between these two expressions? Is there any particular way to know when to use plural object for a plural subject and when to take a singular object for a plural subject? It's the most difficult sphere while constructing a sentence into English as most learners of English compare the English sentences with their native language that causes a lot of disturbance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatical, but they have slightly different meanings

> Books are a great blessing

means that books collectively are one blessing and perhaps implies that there are other **types** of great blessing such as good health or kind friends.

> Books are great blessings

means that each book (or at least each of some set of books) is a blessing in and of itself.

In short,

> plural noun are a singular noun

is considering the nouns in the subject as a single class.

> plural noun are plural nouns

is considering the nouns in the subject as individuals